# Adsense Ads breaking scroll (cutting off content) on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, ads, adsense

We're having trouble with Adsense ads disrupting scroll behavior for the content of a page, on mobile specifically. When you tap (and hold) your finger on an ad, it does not actually scroll up or down the page, but rather simply moves the screen up and cuts everything else above it off. If you tap (and hold) and drag on anything that's NOT an ad, the page scrolls just fine.

I've linked to a video of the issue below.

[Video of scroll behavior issue](https://player.vimeo.com/external/250480325.hd.mp4?s=2645a84adb963efec7f7b5a5cd8298048525d931&profile_id=174)

Here's the markup in JSX (we're using React):

```
<div className="resultsAdContainer">
    <div className="resultsAd" style={{display: 'inline-block', margin: '25px auto 25px auto'}}>
        <ins className="adsbygoogle" style={{display: "block"}} data-ad-client={this.props.dataAdClient} data-ad-slot={this.props.dataAdSlot} data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS selectors:

```
.resultsAdContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.resultsAd {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've tried `touch-action: none` and also tried adding an event listener for `touchmove` and `touchstart` and invoking `.preventDefault()` when an event is fired on the container DIV.

The only thing I've found to work is adding `pointer-events: none` on the resultsAd class. Trouble is, that also disables clicking the ads, which is obviously a no-go. I've tried adding `pointer-events: auto` back later on to the iframe tags with Javascript, but that just resets everything back to the same behavior originally described.

Any ideas how to stop this "cutting off" behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is Necromancy but just sharing this for anyone who had this same issue. I decided to use multiplex instead. It actually let me scroll after. I was using it inside a Material UI FullScreen Dialog if that helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31395020)